# How to prove that two sets are equal (general form)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given $A$ and $B$, then $A = B$ when $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

I have the idea to prove the individual parts, I mean, to prove $A \subseteq B$ and then also $B \subseteq A$ and make it follow that $A = B$

My idea to prove those individual parts is using the contrapositive approach by using a trivial element $x$ for the sake of the proof. Here is my idea (the same procedure for both):

> step 1. Suppose $x \in B$
>
> step 2. Therefore $x \notin A$,
>
> step 3. Thus $x \notin B$ implies $x \notin A$
>
> step 4. so it follows that $A \subseteq B$

I am doubtful if I am missing some steps from steps 1 to 4. **am I missing something?**, **should I make some assumptions respect $x$? which one?**

Once correct, how should I write the complete proof? (I want to make sure how to land the idea correctly)

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I don't see how this proves what I think it is your are proving, but even the statement you are trying to prove is not clear. You want to prove "If $(A \subseteq B \land B \subseteq A) $ then $(A=B)$"?

Comment: If by contradiction, Essentially yes. By contradiction. If $A\subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ assume $A\neq B$, that means $\exists x \in A \land x\notin B \lor x \in B \land x \notin A$. Show both cases lead to a contradiction.

Comment: What's your definition of =? This seems straightforward. If $A\subset B $ and $B\subset A $ then $x \in A \iff x\in B $ and ... that's basically the definition, right?

Answer (score 1):

First, a small mistake: Step 1 should be $x \not \in B$ in order to show the contrapositive that $x \not \in B$ implies $x \not \in A$.

Second, and more importantly, please know that you do not have to use the contraposition method. In order to show $A \subseteq B$, you really need to show that for all $x$: $x \in A $ implies $x \in B$. And yes, to prove that you can prove its contraposition, but  a more direct proof would be:

Step 1. Take any arbitrary $x$ an assume $x \in A$

Step 2. .... Therefore, $x \in B$ (Showing this can take many steps of course, not just 1)

Step 3. Therefore, $x \in A$ implies $ x \in B$

Step 4. So it follows that $A \subseteq B$

So you always have a choice of using either this direct method, or using the contraposition method, and you will have to see which one is easier. Sometimes both ways are easy, sometimes both ways are hard, but sometimes one way is easier (conceptually, at least), than the other way.

Finally, you are asking if you should make any further assumptions about $x$ in step 1. The answer is No: other than the assumption $x \not \in B$ (or assuming $ x \in A$ if you use the direct method), you should *definitely not* make any further assumptions about $x$, because the goal is to show that the implication works for *any* $x$.